# Timeout Expired Error: When using DataReader in a loop

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I get following error:

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' occurred in System.Data.dll
>
> Additional information: Timeout expired.  The timeout period elapsed prior to obtaining a connection from the pool.  This may have occurred because all pooled connections were in use and max pool size was reached.

This is when I am attempting to read a value from database every second using a timer.

Below is the code. I know it's because the SQL connection is not closed. But what could I possibly do to solve it?

```
  public void showcount2(int ID)
        {
            notifyIcon1.Visible = true;
            string count;
            string connString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["Dbconn"].ToString();
            SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connString); // defining sql connection
            connection.Open(); // opening connection
            SqlCommand cmd1 = connection.CreateCommand();
            cmd1.CommandText = "select count from dbo.tblcount where UserID = " + ID;
            DataSet datasetFBK1 = new DataSet();
            SqlDataAdapter dataadapterFBK1 = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd1);
            dataadapterFBK1.Fill(datasetFBK1);
            SqlDataReader dr1 = cmd1.ExecuteReader();
            if (dr1.Read())
            {
                string countcheck;
                countcheck = notifyIcon2.Text;
                count = dr1[0].ToString();
                notifyIcon2.Text = "NCT COUNT FOR COLLEAGUE IS: " + count;
                if (countcheck == notifyIcon2.Text)
                {
                    return;
                }
                else
                {
                    notifyIcon2.BalloonTipText = "NCT COUNT FOR COLLEAGUE IS: " + count;
                    notifyIcon2.ShowBalloonTip(50000);
                }

                //pick a colored icon based on the count of the NCT cases
                if (Convert.ToInt32(count) <= 3)
                {
                    notifyIcon2.Icon = new Icon("C:\\BackupFromPC\\greenicon.ico");
                }
                else if (Convert.ToInt32(count) > 3 && Convert.ToInt32(count) <= 5)
                {
                    notifyIcon2.Icon = new Icon("C:\\BackupFromPC\\yellowicon.ico");

                }
                else if (Convert.ToInt32(count) > 5)
                {
                    notifyIcon2.Icon = new Icon("C:\\BackupFromPC\\redicon.ico");
                }
                //------------------------------
                connection.Close();
            }
            
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I know it's because the SQL connection is not closed. But what could I possibly do to solve it?

Well, *do close it*. The easiest way to do so would be to enclose the usage of the connection in a `using` block:

```
using(SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connString))
{
    // the rest of your code goes here
}
```

The `using` statement translates to a `try/finally` block. And in that `finally` block (which will always be executed when you `return` or otherwise leave the scope) the `connection` will be closed automatically.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. This worked just fine. Appreciate your input.

Answer (score 1):

You should be using using :-)
Everything you use like that will be disposed when exitning the scope.
Including closing SqlConnections

Like this:

```
    using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connString))
    {
        using (SqlDataReader dr1 = cmd1.ExecuteReader())
        {
            if (dr1.Read())
            {
                string countcheck;
                countcheck = notifyIcon2.Text;
                count = dr1[0].ToString();
                notifyIcon2.Text = "NCT COUNT FOR COLLEAGUE IS: " + count;
                if (countcheck == notifyIcon2.Text)
                {
                    return;
                }
                else
                {
                    notifyIcon2.BalloonTipText = "NCT COUNT FOR COLLEAGUE IS: " + count;
                    notifyIcon2.ShowBalloonTip(50000);
                }

                //pick a colored icon based on the count of the NCT cases
                if (Convert.ToInt32(count) <= 3)
                {
                    notifyIcon2.Icon = new Icon("C:\\BackupFromPC\\greenicon.ico");
                }
                else if (Convert.ToInt32(count) > 3 && Convert.ToInt32(count) <= 5)
                {
                    notifyIcon2.Icon = new Icon("C:\\BackupFromPC\\yellowicon.ico");

                }
                else if (Convert.ToInt32(count) > 5)
                {
                    notifyIcon2.Icon = new Icon("C:\\BackupFromPC\\redicon.ico");
                }
                //------------------------------                
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply. Your solution looks good. But I already got this working with suggestion from @Rene. However, I shall give this a try once I am done with this project to have an understanding of this workflow. Appreciate your reply. Thanks again!